# How to say the meaning that an autism student will soon be able to live normally in the community?

Tags: word-choice

Ok, let say there is an autism student studying in a special school and his parents say that they want their son will soon be able to live normally in the community.

Should I use the term "assimilate the society" to express that idea?. Ex, parents want their son will soon assimilate the society.

Comment: I would just say that this is a sensitive topic, and there is considerable potential to cause offence. Rather than thinking about what is "correct" or "clearest", it might be better to find out which phrase is considered most appropriate by the people most affected by the issue. That isn't something which this particular forum is necessarily well-placed to help with.

Comment: I didn't want to put it in the answer, but I support adults on the autism spectrum, as a volunteer. 'In the UK, 'community' is definitely the preferred term.

Comment: Also, in many ways, the student is already assimilated into society,  as a student and in having family to live with. He is not socially isolated. I think you are wanting to convey that he is moving to 'independent living', rather than to his level of participation in society.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up: the adjective for a person diagnosed with autism is 'autistic', i.e.: 'an autistic student'.

To answer your question, "assimilate the society" doesn't make any sense, as in this context the word 'assimilate' means to absorb or incorporate into one's self. You could say "assimilate *into* society", as 'society' in this case is the larger entity that accepts new members.

You might also consider:

- integrate into society
- live comfortably in society
- participate in society

I'd personally simply avoid the use of words like 'normal' or 'regular' as it inherently implies that the autistic person is 'abnormal' or 'irregular', which could be considered offensive to some people.

Answer (score 1):

From a UK perspective, we prefer using 'the [**community**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/community)' to describe:

> a particular area or place considered together with its inhabitants

The student will presumably be moving either to live independently, or in some form of supported housing?

You may wish to convey this transition as follows:

Mr and Mrs X are keen that their autistic son, Y, is supported in his move towards:

- independent community living
- living independently in the local community

*Or:*

Mr and Mrs X would like their autistic son, Y, to live in supported housing within the local community.